# Echo $image where username is $name

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have to echo an image based on which user is logged in. When a user is logged in, the code will check his acces level. Based on that acces level projects will be retrieved. With that retrieval should come an image that is linked to that project.

So if user "Test" is logged in he gets 4 projects, with 4 different images. Currently i have it like this with a link to an image in the folder. But `sporthal.jpg` should be replaced with a variable so that when someone has rights to see the school project, he sees the school project with `school.jpg` instead of `sporthal.jpg`:

```
<div class="projecten">
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Projecten</th></tr></thead>

        <?php
        $sql="SELECT rechten.Projecten_PrID, rechten.Gebruikers_GID, projecten.naam, projecten.Foto 
              FROM rechten 
              INNER JOIN projecten ON rechten.Projecten_PrID = projecten.PrID 
              WHERE Gebruikers_GID = '".$_SESSION['GID']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<hr>\nQuery: $sql");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
            echo 
            ' <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>'.$row["naam"].' </a></td>
                      <td>
                          <a href="project.php?" class="knop">
                              <img src="projecten/sporthal.jpg" width="500" height="250" />
                          </a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>';
        }
        ?>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to associate the images with the projects in your database. After the login process,  query what projects are assigned to each user, and then print the projects' names, followed by the images associated with them.

Comment: Btw you are missing a link here no? `<td>'.$row["naam"].' </a></td>`

Comment: I have saved the username in a session so when i call for .$row["naam"]. it retrieves it from my session. this part works. Also i have associated the images in the database with the projects. But i dont know how to echo them properly

Comment: Your echo is strange to, you create one `tbody` foreach result, you should create only ONE tbody and multiple `tr` instead no? And here you just write `<img src="projecten/sporthal.jpg" width="500" height="250" />`, where is the dynamic part? You should do `<img src="/your/dynamic/src/" width="500" height="250" />`

Comment: using <td> instead of <tr> is purely visual preference that i use to display image and projectinfo side by side. But can you explain what you mean by dynamic? i have saved the images in a database and local. I can call them from local or the database

Comment: @MutatedWhale You said `i have saved the images in a database`, so I assume that you have a table with the path of your image, no? Eg. `table = picture` with `id_picture` and `path_to_picture`, so you need to do is : 1/ Get this `path_to_picture` in your select request `SELECT path_to_picture as path, ... FROM echten INNER...;` 2/ Display the good picture path in your loop : `<img src=".$row['path']." width="500" height="250" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by removing it from the database and by retrieving it from a filestorage like this: (Thank you for your help everyone)

```
<div class="projecten">
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Projecten</th></tr></thead>

    <?php
    $imagepath = "projecten/";
    $sql="SELECT rechten.Projecten_PrID, rechten.Gebruikers_GID, projecten.naam, projecten.Foto 
          FROM rechten 
          INNER JOIN projecten ON rechten.Projecten_PrID = projecten.PrID 
          WHERE Gebruikers_GID = '".$_SESSION['GID']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<hr>\nQuery: $sql");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
        echo 
        ' <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>'.$row["naam"].' </a></td> ';

        echo '
                  <td>
                      <a href="project.php?" class="knop">
                          <img src="'.$imagepath.$row["Projecten_PrID"].'.jpg" width="150" height="75" />
                      </a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
Note : Here I assume `projecten.Foto` is Image. You have define somewhere `$imagepath`  to give complete path of your stored image.

```
<div class="projecten">
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Projecten</th></tr></thead>

        <?php
        $sql="SELECT rechten.Projecten_PrID, rechten.Gebruikers_GID, projecten.naam, projecten.Foto 
              FROM rechten 
              INNER JOIN projecten ON rechten.Projecten_PrID = projecten.PrID 
              WHERE Gebruikers_GID = '".$_SESSION['GID']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<hr>\nQuery: $sql");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
            echo 
            ' <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>'.$row["naam"].' </a></td>
                      <td>
                          <a href="project.php?" class="knop">
                              <img src="'.$imagepath.$row['Foto']." width="500" height="250" />
                          </a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>';
        }
        ?>

    </table>
</div>
```